# You have requested a non-existent service "Doctrine". Did you mean this: "doctrine"?

Tags: php, symfony

After upgrade symfony 2.8 to 3.4 each time i run

```
php bin/console debug:contaier
```

I get :

```
In Container.php line 348:

  You have requested a non-existent service "Doctrine". Did you mean this: "doctrine"?
```

Project worked perfectly with symfony 2.8. How can I fix this dummy error?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to this [blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-dependency-injection-deprecations#deprecated-the-case-insensitivity-of-service-identifiers). It means that from 2.8 to 3.4 a symfony DI container became case sensitive.

```
$this->get('Doctrine');
```

Is no longer equivalent to

```
$this->get('doctrine');
```

So you should look at all config files, controllers and other services that use doctrine and check that they are using the `doctrine` not the `Doctrine`.

Comment: Thanks but where is not any Doctrine reference in my code, i check it using git grep and IDE tools.

Comment: Maybe other packages? Did you upgrade all packages or only `symfony/framework-bundle`? Also you could try delete cache folder manually.

Comment: Yes i update all related package as composer aks for, remove cache manually does not help. thanks